# NodeJS + SockJS + STOMP connection to Java Spring

Tags: java, node.js, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a question - I have java spring web application with websocket,sockjs implementation following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/  and I need to connect with NodeJS to this server application. 
Server app is OK because I managed to connect via web app and it is working but the problem comes when I try to implement it to nodejs. 
so to make this clear
- SERVER is Java Spring MVC + websocket + sockJS
- CLIENT is NodeJS + missing libs (STOMP, SockJS)

I tried maybe 10 different approaches but with no luck, websocket seems to be connected but I have problem to attach stomp to sockjs.

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786323/how-can-i-make-spring-websocket-node-js-client) worked a lot for me

Answer (score 0):

Now sure what other `10 different approaches` you tried, have you tried to use an [official JS Client library](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) for SockJS and then add Stomp to it like this (take from the [official Stomp](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/) page):

```
var Stomp = require('stompjs');
var ws = new SockJS(url);
var client = Stomp.over(ws);
```